# Show code highlighting in suggested edits review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, syntax-highlighting

I've noticed that, when I'm reviewing suggested edits, the code highlighting isn't displayed unless it's explicitly written in the markdown like:

```
<-- language: lang-js -->
```

I guess that when the post is shown in the review queue, SO doesn't try to match the code with the tags. This only happens in the 'Suggested edits' queue, and not in others like 'Triage', 'First Posts' and so on...

I know this is not fundamental to the purpose of a review, but is it by design?